# What determines Catchability of Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-shuffle

I've noticed that after beating a stage, the initial Catchability percentage will be very low, despite being what I would consider a good game. It then adds on additional percentage for moves that were unused.

What I don't understand is how the initial percent is calculated. I can do really well on one stage and get a low percentage, but do pretty badly on another and get a high percentage. How is the Catachability determined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Shuffle#Stages):

> Pokémon have a set capture rate that is added to depending on how many moves a player has left at the end of a battle (Example: 50% plus 5% per move remaining.)
>
> Timed levels have a *per-3-seconds-group bonus* that is added for each time 3 seconds can be subtracted from the time remaining before it becomes zero or negative.
>
> If capture fails and the player has at least 2500 coins, they are offered the choice of buying a Great Ball that has twice the probability of capture of the Poké Ball used for free.

So it's not calculated, it's a fixed value. The only thing you can do to increase the Catchability is end a challenge with a good amount of left moves or time. And eventually use a Great Ball.

Note that Moves+5 and Time+10 **do not** increase capture rate for those bonus moves, so you can't use these items to make it easier to catch a Pokémon.
If you end the stage with 5 or fewer moves, the Pokémon will have the same capture rate as if you beat it with 0 moves remaining.

EDIT:
The latest update introduced a new feature called **Super Catch Power**:

> After successfully completing a stage, if the player fails to catch a Pokémon with their first Poké Ball (before using a Great Ball), they have a chance of being offered a "Super Catch Power". This Super Catch Power provides a somewhat random boost on top of the Great Ball's boost (the player still uses a Great Ball, and can use the same number of Great Balls as they could without the "Super Catch Power")